# EBean enhancement issue [POJO not enhanced]

Tags: vert.x, ebean

I am Using Ebean and Vert.x for my cron jobs.

But for some reason Entities are not being enhanced by ebean-maven-plugin.

Here is what I am using:

```
              <plugin>
                <groupId>io.ebean</groupId>
                <artifactId>ebean-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>12.1.12</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>main</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformArgs>debug=1</transformArgs>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enhance</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

My entity:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "targeting_locations")
public class TargetingLocations {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Long id;
// other properties

}
```

Here is the error code:

```
2020-04-15 19:39:26,671  i.e.s.d.BeanDescriptorManager - Error in deployment
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bean class com.xxx.model.TargetingLocations is not enhanced?
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.setEntityBeanClass(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1414)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.createByteCode(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1286)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readDeployAssociations(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1208)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readEntityDeploymentAssociations(BeanDescriptorManager.java:711)
```

From different posts, could not really figure out what is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your domain should extend io.ebean.Model 
Rest looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have the same problem recently and I change from `ebean-maven-plugin` to `tiles-maven-plugin`. It will enchance your Ebean Entity. This is the plugin:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.repaint.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <tiles>
                    <tile>org.avaje.tile:java-compile:1.1</tile>
                    <tile>io.ebean.tile:enhancement:5.3</tile>
                </tiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

By using tiles-maven-plugin you only need this ebean dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.ebean</groupId>
        <artifactId>ebean</artifactId>
        <version>11.22.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Hope it helps. Thank you.